# Impala SSL encryption too slow

Tags: ssl, tableau-api, impala

We are using Tableau Server and Desktop with Impala (Impala is running on our in-house hadoop cluster)

We recently activated the LDAP user authentication in Impala and wanted to secure the user credentials transmission from Tableau to Impala. For this, we enabled SSL encryption in Impala, which is applied to traffic between users (including Tableau) and Impala. However, this encryption is not only applied to user credentials but to ALL THE TRAFFIC between user and Impala. This incredibly slows down the data transfer between the Tableau and Impala.

Is there a way to encrypt only the user credentials and not ALL THE TRAFFIC between user and Impala ? (OR to speed up the encryption ?)

Thanks and regards, 
Zeeshan

Comment: Last time I measured SSL overhead it was 3x, not 'incredibly'. What were your measurements?

Comment: What version are you using? This may be related to IMPALA-1556 and IMPALA-1442.

Comment: Hi again, it is actually 'incredibly' slow. A factor of at least 40x. I was also surprised at it. And I still haven't found a solution.